# Spring kafka and Kafka Cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I've configured 3 kafka's in cluster and I'm trying to use with spring-kafka.

But After I kill the kafka leader I'm not able to send other messages to queue.

I'm setting the spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers property as: "kafka-1:9092;kafka-2:9093,kafka-3:9094" and all of names in my hosts file.

Kafka version 0.10

Some knows how the correct configuration?

**Edit**

I have tested one thing and happened a strange behavior.
When I start the service I send a message to topic( to force the creation)

Code:

```
@Bean
public KafkaSyncListener synchronousListener(MessageSender sender, KafkaProperties prop) {
    sender.send(prop.getSynchronousTopic(), "Message to force create the topic! Run, Forrest, Run!");
    return new KafkaSyncListener();
}
```

So, In this time I did not start the kafka-1 server( just the others) and It happened the exception:

> org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaProducerException: Failed to send;
>   nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException:
>   Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.

It seems spring-kafka just tries to connect on the first bootstrap server.
I'm using spring-kafka 1.3.5.RELEASE and kafka 0.10.1.1

**Edit 2**

I have done the test that you did. It happens the same when I remove the first docker container (kafka-1) the leader have changed. So, My consumer(spring service) does not able to consume the messages.
But when I start the kafka-1 again the service get all messages
My consumer ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory:

```
{
  key.deserializer=class
  org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer,
  value.deserializer=class
  org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer,
  max.poll.records=500,
  group.id=mongo-adapter-service,
  ssl.keystore.location=/certs/kafka.keystore.jks,
  bootstrap.servers=[kafka-2:9093, kafka-1:9092, kafka-3:9094],
auto.commit.interval.ms=100,
security.protocol=SSL,
max.request.size=5242880,
ssl.truststore.location=/certs/kafka.keystore.jks,
auto.offset.reset=earliest
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You need a comma between server addresses, not a semicolon.

**EDIT**

I just ran a test with no problems:

```
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092,localhost:9093,localhost:9094
```

and

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So50804678Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So50804678Application.class, args);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "foo", topics = "so50804678")
    public void in(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return new NewTopic("so50804678", 1, (short) 3);
    }

}
```

and

```
$ kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:2181 --describe --topic so50804678
Topic:so50804678    PartitionCount:1    ReplicationFactor:3 Configs:
    Topic: so50804678   Partition: 0    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0,1,2 Isr: 0,1,2
```

Killed the leader, and

```
$ kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:2181 --describe --topic so50804678
Topic:so50804678    PartitionCount:1    ReplicationFactor:3 Configs:
    Topic: so50804678   Partition: 0    Leader: 1   Replicas: 0,1,2 Isr: 1,2
```

and

```
$ kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092,localhost:9093,localhost:9093 --topic so50804678
```

Sent a message and it was received by the app; no errors in the log except a WARN:

> [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=foo] Connection to node 0 could not be established. Broker may not be available.

I then restarted the dead server; stopped my app; then added this code...

```
@Bean
public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
    return args -> {
        while(true) {
            System.out.println(template.send("so50804678", "foo").get().getRecordMetadata());
            Thread.sleep(3_000);
        }
    };
}
```

Again, killing the current leader had no impact; everything recovered ok.

You may need to tweak the listeners/advertised.listeners properties in your server props. Since my brokers are all on local host, I left them to default.

Comment: I have done. So now, when the leader goes down i'm able to put a message in the queue, but the consumer cannot consume. But if I start the previous leader again, the consumer can take the message. Do you know the problem?. Thx for the answer

Comment: Sounds like the topic is not replicated on the other broker(s) perhaps. `$ kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:2181 --describe --topic myTopic`.

Comment: I executed the command in kafka-2 and kafka-3 and both returned:
# ./kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper 172.17.0.1:2182 --describe --topic database_request
Topic:database_request PartitionCount:1 ReplicationFactor:3 Configs:
 Topic: database_request Partition: 0 Leader: 3 Replicas: 1,3,2 Isr: 3,2
Seems right?

Comment: Should The kafka cluster configuration on Spring spring be simple? Like just fill the bootstrap servers with nodes and should everthing work?

Comment: Please, see my edit 2. I have no words to thank you.

Comment: For EDIT1: Reduce the producer property `max.block.ms` from its default (60 seconds) and set the producer property `retries`. For EDIT2 - I am not familiar with docker, but my guess is the listener/advertised.listener properties need to be set so that the brokers are properly visible (it used to be `advertised.host.name` - I have had similar problems accessing my cluster on localhost from a different machine in the cluster). You should refer to the Kafka documentation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173002/discussion-between-rodolfo-oliveira-and-gary-russell).